# Get HTML elements from variable string

Tags: javascript

I've got a string with some **HTML** in it.
I'd like to get the first two paragraphs

```
<p>content</p><p>content 2</p>
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Is this variable is a string with HTML in it or DOM nodes?

Comment: What  have you tried?

Comment: Could you paste the contents of an example to see the structure of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two examples:

```
var string = "<p>content</p><p>content 2</p>";




// EXAMPLE 1
var parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, "text/html");
var paragraphs = parser.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i=0; i<paragraphs.length; i++){
  console.log( paragraphs[i].innerHTML ); // or use `outerHTML`
}
// "content"
// "content 2"



// EXAMPLE 2
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', string);  
var paragraphs = el.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i=0; i<paragraphs.length; i++){
  console.log( paragraphs[i].innerHTML ); // or use `outerHTML`
}
// "content"
// "content 2"
```

if you want instead to really get

```
// "<p>content</p>"
// "<p>content 2</p>"
```

simply replace in both examples `innerHTML` with `outerHTML`

if you want to manipulate the current HTMLParagraphElement than simply use the `paragraph[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Create a DOM element and put your html in it, like so:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = "<html><p>content</p></html>"
```

You can then get the desired parts as a NodeList:

```
element.getElementsByTagName('p');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using jQuery:

```
var example = "<div><p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p></div>";
var parsed = $(example);
parsed.find("p"); //Returns all <p> elements
parsed.find("p")[0]; //Returns the first <p> element
parsed.find("p")[1]; //Returns the second <p> element
```